# Vertical shift of UITableViewCell origin in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a controller displaying both a status bar and navigation bar, and containing a single UITableView.  The UITableView is set programmatically to contain 2 sections, each with a single UITableViewCell and header.  Up to and including iOS version 4.3.2, the UITableView displays the two sections stacked nicely, one on top of the other, and a log inserted into the method

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

reveals that the vertical position of UITableViewCells within the superview are 30.00 and 101.00 respectively.  However, when running the same code on iOS5.0, the second section is vertically shifted downward, and the log reveals positions of 30.00 and 144.00 respectively.  I've been trying to run this down, but so far no luck.  Any ideas as to what could have changed in the new version of the OS that could be causing this behavior?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Also of note, the text of the second header was blurred as of iOS5.0, but applying a ceiling function to the value returned by

```
(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

took care of the problem.  The two issues are obviously related, but no amount of tinkering has gotten me closer to the source.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that for this particular UITableView, a footer was not implemented, so the value returned by the `heightForFooterInSection:` method was superfluous.  It would seem that in iOS4.3 and below, if the footer was indeed empty, the system disregarded the footer entirely, regardless of the "height" method.  However, iOS5.0 respected the method and allotted the space, whether or not anything was actually occupying that space.  Removing the unnecessary method solved the problem.